# How to keep selected values in html in flask app

Tags: python, html, flask

> This if my html file and i just want to keep the selected values in the dropdown menu after clicked. That's only my problem I hope for your response. I try a lot of methods but I can't solve my problem. Thankyou for the help

```
<form action="{{url_for('values')}}" method='POST'>
     <div class="s1">
<div class="s1_lbl">
         <label style="font-weight: bold; color:white;">Select a Fish:</label>
<select name="fish" class="dropdown">
    <optgroup label="BRACKISHWATER FISHPOND">
      <option value="BF - Milkfish">BF - Milkfish</option>
          <option value="BF - Tilapia">BF - Tilapia</option>
          <option value="BF - Tiger prawn">BF - Tiger Prawn</option>
            <option value="BF - Mudcrab">BF - Mudcrab</option>
            <option value="BF - Endeavor prawn">BF - Endeavor prawn</option>
            <option value="BF - White shrimp">BF - White shrimp</option>
            <option value="BF - Grouper">BF - Grouper</option>
            <option value="BF - Siganid">BF - Siganid</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

         <label style="font-weight: bold; color:white;">Number of Quarter/s:</label>
         <select name="quarter"  class="dropdown2">
          <option value="0">1 (JANUARY-MARCH)</option>
          <option value="1">2 (APRIL-JUNE)</option>
          <option value="2">3 (JULY-SEPTEMBER)</option>
          <option value="3">4 (OCTOBER-DECEMBER)</option>
        </select>
</div>
         <div class="btn_pos">
     <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Frontend**
You can save selected data in localstorage when you click the button and then select the option which its value is equal to the save data.

OR
**Backend**
use session storage

this code snippet is frontend solution, link this javascript code to your html and it should work fine

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn_pos .btn');
let fishDropdown = document.querySelector('[name=fish]');
let quarterDropdown = document.querySelector('[name=quarter]');
    
// select last clicked fish option
document.querySelectorAll('[name=fish] option').forEach(el => {
    el.value == localStorage.getItem('savedFish') && el.setAttribute('selected', true);
});

// select last clicked quarter option
document.querySelectorAll('[name=quarter] option').forEach(el => {
    el.value == localStorage.getItem('savedQuarter') && el.setAttribute('selected', true);
});

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    let selectedFish = fishDropdown.value;
    let selectedQuarter = quarterDropdown.value;

    localStorage.setItem('savedFish', selectedFish);
    localStorage.setItem('savedQuarter', selectedQuarter);
});
```

```html
<div class="s1_lbl">
    <label style="font-weight: bold; color:white;">Select a Fish:</label>
    <select name="fish" class="dropdown">
        <optgroup label="BRACKISHWATER FISHPOND">
            <option value="BF - Milkfish">BF - Milkfish</option>
            <option value="BF - Tilapia">BF - Tilapia</option>
            <option value="BF - Tiger prawn">BF - Tiger Prawn</option>
            <option value="BF - Mudcrab">BF - Mudcrab</option>
            <option value="BF - Endeavor prawn">BF - Endeavor prawn</option>
            <option value="BF - White shrimp">BF - White shrimp</option>
            <option value="BF - Grouper">BF - Grouper</option>
            <option value="BF - Siganid">BF - Siganid</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <label style="font-weight: bold; color:white;">Number of Quarter/s:</label>
    <select name="quarter" class="dropdown2">
        <option value="0">1 (JANUARY-MARCH)</option>
        <option value="1">2 (APRIL-JUNE)</option>
        <option value="2">3 (JULY-SEPTEMBER)</option>
        <option value="3">4 (OCTOBER-DECEMBER)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="btn_pos">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```